Unable to open experience cloud site in an iframe
I am having an omniscript on an experience cloud site. I want to access another experience cloud site inside the omniscript for which I am using an lwc component in the omniscript which has an iframe which should open the second experience cloud site.
The problem I am facing is that when I am trying to open the second experience cloud's site inside the iframe I am getting the error 'Site refused to connect'. When I checked the console I saw the error 'Refused to frame 'https://adb-dev-ed.my.site.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".'
These are the security settings of the target experience cloud site:

I was expecting if the user is not already logged in then the user should be redirected to the login page of the experience cloud site but that is not happening. What could be the alternative?

Have you already set the Trusted Site as decribed in the documentation?

Yes, I have tried that already but I get the same error

Do you have checked this?

Integration of Experience Builder Site into any Websites Using iframes Not Supported

